# UitableView Slide Menu with uiimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm using uitableView slide menu from this link [IOS-Slide-Menu](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu); and i try to enter image inside the cell to be fitted with cell; there's some code from i used

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"rightMenuCell"];
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sidebutton-exr"];

            break;

        case 1:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sidebutton-Fooj"];    


            break;

        case 2:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sidebutton-less.png"];

            break;

        case 3:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sidebutton-Ped.png"];

            break;
        case 4:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sidebutton-Ramadan.png"];
            break;
        case 5:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sidebutton-risk.png"];
            break;
        case 6:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sidebutton-travel.png"];
            break;
        case 7:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sidebutton-Haj.png"];

            break;
        }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

but what i gain as image below
[image: Screen Shoot]

the image as shown on the screen shoot not on the right; what i need to make the image on the right

Answer (score 1):

i think its the issue with your side menu controller, the right menu is overlapped by the view in front. i would suggest you to try

MMDrawer:https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController
SWRevealViewController:https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

for the side menu option